# instead of getting a color i get this [31mHello World !!![0m using termcolor and colored

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, colors, termcolor

I tried using different methods, the results are the same in cmd and poweshell however i couldnt get it to show the color. The code i used:

```
from termcolor import *
print(colored('Hello World !!!', "red"))
```

Output:

```
"[31mHello World !!![0m"
```

I get this weird charachters around "Hello World !!!" and it doesn't appear colored.

Comment: Those *"weird charachters [sic]"* **are** the color codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Comment: Not all consoles support ANSI escape codes used for coloring (among other things). It seems that your current console doesn't support them

Comment: but what about powershell? doesn't it support coloring? what console does support coloring? and is there any way i could implement it in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your code in linux it would give you your desired output not in windows. Powershell does support coloring of output, you need to specify -ForegroundColor  parameter like

```
Write-Host "PREREQUISITIES" -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

Comment: Powershell and CMD console